# asyncio, aiohttp. Запуск нескольких сессий которые выполняют несколько запросов. Проблема в закрытии сессий

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, aiohttp

### Задача

Необходимо запустить несколько сессий и что бы каждая из них выполнила определенное количество запросов. Хочу отметить, что необходимо именно несколько сессий, а не одна, как представлено почти во всех примерах к aiohttp. Ниже представлен код в котором:

1. через loop запускается курутина **run**
2. в run создается 3 сессии и столько же задач(**runfetchers**) в которые передаются созданные сессии и списки для загрузки
3. в каждом **runfetchers** запускается 20 **fetch** на одну сессию.
4. после загрузки все результаты должны собраться в одном месте и отрытые сессии - закрыться.

### Проблема

1. Я только начал разбираться в asyncio\aiohttp и возможно не
   правильно размышляю, прошу поправить меня.
2. Код рабочий, но на закрытии открытых сессий происходит ошибка (как я
   только не пробовал)

До этого пробовал сделать все через одну сессию и все прекрасно работает, как я использовал код из [примеров](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html) в которых используется контекстный менеджер, который сам закрывал сессию, и в примерах использовался один уровень "погружения".

### Код

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import math

# генератор который будет разрезать списки
def listpartial(inlist, n):
    if n > 0:
        s = math.ceil(len(inlist) / n)
        for q in range(s):
            yield inlist[q * n:(q + 1) * n]

# собсвенно загрузчик страниц
async def fetch(num, session):
    try:
        url = f'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{num}'
        async with session.get(url) as r:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1, 0.3)
            return await r.text(encoding='utf-8')
    except Exception as e:
        print('fetch', e)
        return ''

async def runfetchers(numlist, session):
    tasks2 = []
    # создам количество задач на загрузку каждого элемента
    for num in numlist:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(num, session))
        tasks2.append(task)

    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks2)
    return responses

async def run(allnums):
    tasks = []
    sessions = []
    # получии объект генератор который будет выдавать списки по 20 элементов
    numlist = listpartial(allnums, 20)
    # создам 3 сессии и столько же задач и запущу их
    for _ in range(3):
        session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        sessions.append(session)
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(runfetchers(next(numlist), session))
        tasks.append(task)

    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    # закрываю открытые сессии
    # ?????? как закрыть вот эти сессии
    # for i in sessions:
    #     sessions[i].close()
    return responses

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = [x for x in range(1200)]

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(nums))
    res = loop.run_until_complete(future)

    print(res)
```

### Заключение

Ответ на мой вопрос представлен ниже (еще раз спасибо), но я параллельно написал код который решает мою задачу по другому, может кому то пригодится:

```
# собсвенно загрузчик страниц
async def fetch(num, session):
    try:
        url = f'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{num}'
        async with session.get(url) as r:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1, 0.3)
            return await r.text(encoding='utf-8')
    except Exception as e:
        print('fetch', e)
        return ''

# запустим сессию, которая запустит несколько запросов
# и потом сама себя закроет
async def start_sesssion(numlst):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        futs = [asyncio.create_task(fetch(n, session)) for n in numlst]
        return await asyncio.gather(*futs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = [x for x in range(1200)]

    numlist = listpartial(nums, 20)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [loop.create_task(start_sesssion(next(numlist))) for i in range(3)]
    result = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*futures))

    print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ClientSession.close()](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientSession.close) - это сопрограмма, поэтому

```
for session in sessions:
    await session.close()
```

или

```
await asyncio.wait([s.close() for s in sessions])
```

Comment: я так пробовал, TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not ClientSession

Comment: и все равно ошибка connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x00000171D54C8588>, 307372.078), 
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x00000171D52FC9E8>
Unclosed connector

Comment: @AlexNasov даже не обратил внимания, что у вас цикл неправильно написан. Исправил.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все заработало. А можете в двух словах объяснить почему представленный мной вариант не правильный?

Comment: @AlexNasov в Python переменная цикла содержит элемент итерируемой коллекции, а не его индекс.

Comment: Блин, точно....